# Using pthread to print 2-d array

Tags: c++, pthreads, pthread-join

So i have an assignment that says I have create a 2-d array[5][12] with random values between 1-99. Then using pthreads, I have to either add 1 or subtract 1 to each element in the array and then print the results and divide the process into either 2, 3, or 4 threads. The number of threads depends on the what the user inputs on the command line. I have code that compiles and runs. However, my desired output is only printed when the number 3 is entered. Could you guys tell me where I went wrong in my code? I'm having trouble understanding pthreads to begin with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int list[5][12];
int rows = 5;
int cols = 12;
int threadc;

void *threadf(void *arg)
{
    int x = (int) arg;
    for(int i = (x*60)/threadc; i < ((x+1) * 60)/threadc; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            if (list[i][j] % 2 == 0)
                list[i][j] += 1;
            else
                list[i][j] -= 1;
        }
    }
}

void cArray()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            list[i][j] = rand() % 99 + 1;
        }
    }

}

void pArray(int list[][12], int rows, int cols)
{
    cout << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << list[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) exit(0);
    threadc = atoi(argv[1]);
    assert(threadc >= 2 && threadc <=4);
    pthread_t *thread;
    thread = new pthread_t [threadc];
    if(thread == NULL)
        exit(0);
    cArray();
    cout << "2-d Array: ";
    pArray(list, rows, cols);
    int t;
    for(int i = 0; i < threadc; i++)
    {
        t = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, threadf, (void *)i);
        if (t != 0)
            return 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < threadc; i++)
    {
        t = pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
        if(t != 0)
            return 1;
    }  
    cout << "Modified 2-d Array: ";
    pArray(list, rows, cols);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes it is. Is that not allowed here?

Comment: It's allowed and so far it looks like you are showing your work. Recommend a few changes though: "my desired output" Show this. Also show what you are getting instead. Recommendation: Start without the random numbers so you can test the same numbers over and over until you have your threading sorted out. Easier to spot improvements or errors.

Comment: `int x = (int) arg;` is high risk. `int` and pointer may not be the same size. Also means that the cast in `t = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, threadf, (void *)i);` may have unpleasant results. Sidenote: The first should be illegal in C++ (Strict Aliasing Rule, I  believe)

Comment: A function with a return type other than `void` must always return something `threadf` doesn't making the program invalid. Weird stuff will result and sadly the weird stuff may be exactly what you expect. [See Undefined Behaviour.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: Yea this definitely helped. I've been doing programming for about a year now. And there is still a lot I screw up on. Just so much to know!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somehow `thread_join` returns an error code(`22` in my case) when the number of threads created is 2. If you remove the return statement in the second loop, your program prints the final output.

```
for(int i = 0; i < threadc; i++)
{
    t = pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    if (t != 0) 
        return 1; // <- your program works if you comment out this.


}
```

According to this link: http://minirighi.sourceforge.net/html/errno_8h.html
22 is EINVAL which means 'thread is un-joinable'.

Since you care about the return value of pthread_join, I would advise to add a successful termination function (`pthread_exit(NULL);`) at the end of your `thredf`. Also, to avoid buffer overrun as mentioned by @user4581301, you could pass a pointer to the data.

So `thredf` would be like

```
void *threadf(void *arg)
{
    cout << endl;
    int x = *((int*)arg); // <- NOTICE HERE!
    for(int i = (x*60)/threadc; i < ((x+1) * 60)/threadc; i++)
      //...
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL); // <- NOTICE HERE!
}
```

And the main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) exit(0);
    threadc = atoi(argv[1]);
    assert(threadc >= 2 && threadc <=4);
    pthread_t *thread;
    thread = new pthread_t [threadc];
    int *data = new int[threadc]; // <- NOTICE HERE!

    if(thread == NULL)
        exit(0);
    cArray();
    cout << "2-d Array: ";
    pArray(list, rows, cols);
    int t;
    for(int i = 0; i < threadc; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i;
        //                                                NOTICE HERE!
        t = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, threadf, (void *)(&data[i])); 
        if (t != 0)
            return 1;
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Sort of. This works by fluke. 0x03 means no such thread, so you're just masking another error. What you want to find out is why is there no second thread?

Comment: @user For the sake of your solution you do not have to care much what thread_join returns. Because there are a few conditions where the error returned could be useful: a thread is deadlocked or EINVAL. If you look closely even in the POSIX tutorials, most of the example do not look at what this function returns. The most fundamental job for a parent thread to call this function is to block until all its child threads terminate. I have been writing multithreaded programs for years and I have not cared what this function returns. It is its behavior that matters.

Comment: Not my solution, dude. The real problem is a buffer overrun up in `threadf`and your answer here just hides that.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at the outer for loop in `threadf` for x = 0 and threadc = 4

```
    for(int i = (0*60)/4; i < ((0+1) * 60)/4; i++)
    for(int i = 0; i < (1 * 60)/4; i++)
    for(int i = 0; i < 60/4; i++)
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
```

`i` ranges from 0 to 14. i is being used like this: `list[i][j]`, so consider where writes to `list[14][11]` will go. Well outside the bounds defined by `int list[5][12];` Bad smurf will happen. Undefined behaviour, so technically no one knows what will happen. We can make some pretty good guesses though.

```
int list[5][12];
int rows = 5; // probably overwritten by write to list[6][0]
int cols = 12; // probably overwritten by write to list[6][1]
int threadc; // probably overwritten by write to list[6][3]
```

So `row` and `column` are moving, but no one cares. The code never uses them. But `threadc`... That's used all over the place. In fact, it's used in the loop exit condition. More badness is likely to occur here. It also determines the number of threads to be created and joined. Some threads may not be created. The program may try to join more threads than exist.

Anyway, Undefined Behaviour. I suppose we should all be glad that the compiler didn't generate code that ordered a tactical nuke strike. Since this is a homework question I'm not going to unravel the math OP requires to make their `for` loop correctly divvy up the work across multiple threads, but will suggest that they look into treating the array as a 1D array of size 5*12 and doing the 1D->2D indexing themselves in a single `for` loop.

Other notes:

use `uintptr_t` instead of `int` for `i` in `main` and `x` in `threadf`. `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to convert to a `void *`

Use an unsigned variable like `size_t` for the loop counters and array indexers. They play nicely with `uintptr_t` and you almost never want a negative array index.

Use a `std::vector` instead of a pointer and `new` for the thread list. If you have to use `new` and a pointer, remember to delete the list when you're done with it.

See if you can use `std::thread` instead of the `pthread`s.

Add a `return` to `threadf`.